# Isomorphisms of magmas that are subsets of R

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma

Let there be two sets $A, B\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ and let there be two binary operations $*_M$ and $*_N$. Under what circumstances is $(A,*_M)\cong(B,*_N)$?

I have found a couple of general working cases. If $a*_Nb=(a^n*_Mb^n)^{1/n}$, then $(\Bbb{R}^+,*_M)\cong(\Bbb{R}^+,*_N)$ using the function $f(a)=a^n$. Also, using similar logic, the function $f(x)=\ln(x)$ provides $(\Bbb{R},*_M)\cong(\Bbb{R}^+,*_N)$, when $a*_Nb=e^{\ln(a)*_M\ln(b)}$.

Do isomorphisms only occur if, given proper $A,B$, when $a*_Mb=f^{-1}\Big(f(a)*_Nf(b)\Big)$?

Given that when trying to find an isomorphism between(both are on $\Bbb{R}$): $a*_Mb=a+b+ab$ and $a*_Mb=a^2+b^2$, you get the equation $f(a)^2+f(b)^2=f(a+b+ab)$, which has solutions $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=\pm{1\over2}$. While I know $f(x)=0$ is a trivial solution for any two magma, $f(x)={1\over2}$ is not, and does reflect something about the nature of the equation. I know that $f(x)$ must be a bijection for $(A,*_M)\cong(B,*_N)$, so is there anything the existence of this function shows other than just both $*_M$ and $*_N$ are quadratic?

Comment: If the binary operations are completely general, there seems to be no point to stipulating that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I'm only interested in when they are subsets of $\Bbb{R}$, even if it doesn't generally depend on it being that way.

Comment: I'm now realizing that the answers to my questions are pretty obvious. Is there any way to close the question without deleting it?

Comment: @opfromthestart What bof means is that this is only saying that $A,B$ have cardinality at most continuum, and nothing of the structure of $\mathbb R$ is present in this question.  It seems unlikely you will find an answer that is satisfying, in the sense that any characterization that is complete would just be a tautology.